# Draggable Pie Chart Android

Tags: android, pie-chart, seekbar

I would like to add a Pie Chart which you can touch at the end of its slices and move them so that the size of the slices increases or shrinks dynamically 
[image]
I tried to use a multiple circular seek bar library, but it doesn´t create the result, I was hoping for. The Problem here is, that you can drag the pointer over the maximum and the pointers are going crazy.

Maybe you have an idea how I could realize this idea. I am a Beginner in Android Development. I'm grateful for any advice.

Comment: check this lib https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Comment: i tried to use this lib before, but i didnt manage to adress the slices seperately. The pie chart just spins. Do you know how i can do it?